# Kafka Spark Streaming cache

Tags: java, apache-spark

I have been getting data from one kafka topics in the form of `JavaPairInputDStream` (with twitter streaming api), plan is getting data from two topics checking for duplication with tweet_id and if its not in the package (package is for sending back to kafka), add it. Also i want to cache data for x mins then work on it.

I can get data from kafka topic and output it with

```
stream.foreachRDD(rdd -> {
    System.out.println("--- New RDD with " + rdd.partitions().size()
     + " partitions and " + rdd.count() + " records");
     rdd.foreach(record -> System.out.println(record._2));});
```

But i cant manage to cache it. Tried `rdd.cache()` and persist with `count()`. but it doesn't seem to do trick or i just wasn't able to understand it.

Anyone can guide me how to do this stuff?

Answer (score 0):

Okay so its impossible to cache rdd like this it seems. I created another rdd and I'm using union() whenever stream creates new rdd and caching this way.